.py ran using Launcher- How to close shell and editor windows?
I am once again back to the place of a .py file that works, and I can even open it in Launcher. The window opens for a file to be selected, select file and the 3D graph plot appears, and  all tools for viewing work, and the image can be saved.
The window for choosing a file doesn't close.
As I am just wanting to run the script- is there a way to just run the shell and editor windows in the background?
and close the selection window?
Here is the relevant code for the file selection and reading:
import  tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
print(file_path)

df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
print(df.head)
print(df.columns)

Thank you

As a follow-up after reading a number of similar post i've tried the suggestions. Add root.destroy()  , root.iconify(), several variations involving buttons. At best it just slows run time, but doesn't resolve the issue, and several instance generated errors stopping the script from running.  From the number of related questions this seems to be a somewhat common issue.   Perhaps there is another way to select a .xlsx file that doesn't use tkinter?
